# SQL get the time of different rows

Tags: sql, database, select

I want to do a select that gives me the time of an employee resolving a ticket.
The problem is that the ticket is divided in actions, so its not only getting the time of a row, it can be from n rows.

This is an abbreviation of what I have:

Tickets

```
TicketID | Days | Hours | Minutes
------------------------------------------------
  12     |   0  |   2   | 32
  12     |   1  |   0   | 12
  12     |   4  |   6   | 0
  13     |   2  |   5   | 12
  13     |   0  |   2   | 33
```

And this is what I want to get:

```
TicketID | Time (in minutes) 
------------------------------------------------
   12    |       2994
   13    |       1425
```

(Or just one row with the condition where specifying TicketID)

This is the select that im doing right now:

```
select distinct ((Days*8)*60) + (Hours*60) + Minutes from Tickets where ticketid = 12
```

But is not working as I want.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: You don't want them `distinct`, you want them `summed`

Comment: In general you would need a `group by` but why are you expecting `ticketid = 13` in the result if you have `where ticketid = 12` in your query?

Comment: I added "(Or just one row with the condition where specifying TicketID)" after that to not cause confusion, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select ticketid, sum((Days*8)*60), sum((Hours*60)), sum (Minutes)
from tickets
group by ticketid
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select TicketID, sum((Days*8)*60) + sum(Hours*60) + sum(Minutes) as Time_in_minutes
from Tickets 
group by TicketID
```

Distinct, as you were trying before, takes each row in the source table (Tickets) and filters out all of the duplicate rows.  Instead, you are trying to sum up the days, minutes, and hours for each ticket.  So sum them up, and group by the ticket number.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT  TicketID, (Sum(Minutes)+(Sum(Hours)*60)+(sum(Days)*24*60) ) time  
FROM  Tickets Group by TicketID
```